# Meteor check text before database insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I have a simple textarea which people can insert a paragraph of text. A user doesn't have to be logged in to submit, and the submit will be displayed in the browser straight away.

My question is around validating the text in the client. I am planning to use .allow then insert in the client. What is the best way to check that the text is not something which will do something harmful in the database once the data is committed?

I am new to web development, so I am not sure if anyone can write some harmful text which when submitted will delete the entire database once it is inserted, or do something else harmful.

It may be impossible, but I was wondering if anyone checked the schema for anything harmful before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is really two questions.

One: Can someone insert malicious text into the database (like SQL injection)?

The answer to this is no, nothing they write can get directly executed. For instance, they could enter the text: "function(){ /*do some naughty things*/ }", which would just end up as a string in whatever document you store it in.

Two: How do I validate data before inserting into the database?

Regardless of whether query injection attacks are a significant risk or not, any web-application should always expect and deal with bogus form entries. In terms of validation, you have a lot of options out there. My personal favorite is [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2), which will automatically validate all data against a schema you define when creating the collection.You can easily define min/max lengths, type restrictions, or use the custom option to define a custom function to validate a field. This is a really easy way to make sure all your data get's validated before inserting into the database.